# calculating Probability and prediction.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am trying to calculate the probability for admission to a restaurant, in foot forward to have a rough idea to predict how many admissions would be there in 5 years from now.

The question is: is 18 months of historical data enough to calculate it?

E.g: on an average 2000 people visited cafeA in last 18 month
and 3000 visited cafeB in last 18 months

Kindly help.

Comment: This is not clear. What data do you have and what, exactly, is it you are trying to predict?  Note:  predicting future business events on past performance can be fairly hopeless.  Things change.  Competition comes and goes,  consumer interest changes.  If you have high equipment costs, long range amortization becomes a problem.  And so on.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the comment : )